# How should I display my code inside of my Java program?

Tags: java, joptionpane, jtextpane

I apologize if this question is too "general";
But my question is very specific to what I am programming and I was not able to find a descent answer anywhere else.

I am creating a "Proof of Concept" program for extra credit in my calc class.
Now that the program is finished, I want to make a way to view the coding of the program to show the teacher and explain what I did.

My first thought was to use a JTextPane, but how would that work?
I want to find some way to display all the lines of coding, keeping the structure of coding that Java/Eclipse uses.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

-Steven

Comment: Why can't you just open it in a text editor?

Comment: Why not make a PowerPoint presentation ? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Just show how your program works, the show some code examples from it.

Comment: I could use a text editor, or a powerpoint.
But there must be some way to display the code,
I am fairly new to Java and I want to find a solution to the problem instead of working around it,
It's not a big deal if I don't get it to work. The program still works, but I would prefer to get this working the way I originally intended.  If this is not possible, then I guess I am out of luck and I will just link to a website and post my code there.

Comment: If you are interested in code formating like colors of elements you can try to copy-paste code from Eclipse it to Office Word document. It holds format settings (at least works for me when I create notes with Java code)

Comment: I'm more interested in having the lines displayed correctly,
like all the spaces and indents. So it doesn't look like a huge mess. But thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use system.out.println and get a free account at https://github.com/ and upload your code and the output of your programs . Send the link to your professor ..I think he  will be impressed not only by your work but also by how you are presenting your code to him/her to review it.

good luck, I am already impressed that you are searching online to best present your work for that you deserve an A+ too. keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

If I was your teacher, I'd prefer to be shown your code within an IDE (such as Eclipse). Then I could browse around as I pleased and see it execute in front of me.

IDEs are *built* for looking at code :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am preferring you to use your IDE , but anyway :
Maybe i am wrong but I think the only way is to get the codes from the (.java) file 
and copy it to TextArea but it's not perfect like your IDE.
I will not post the whole program just the function hope it will be useful for you

```
  Scanner sc = null;
    try{
        sc=new Scanner(new File("yourProgram.java"));
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
    String line = "";
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        jTextArea1.append(line=sc.nextLine()+"\n");   
    }
```